# I can manage myself

Tags: phrases

If someone offer his/her help, is it possible to answer in polite form like that - "I can manage myself"?

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/ might be a better fit, depending on what kind of answers you're seeking.

Answer (score 4):

You can say one of the following (in your most humble and polite voice ;) ):

1. Thank you for coming forward to help me, but I am fine.
2. Oh, thank you so much, but I am fine. (or) Oh! Thank you so much! But I am fine.
3. I appreciate your help, but I am good.
4. I appreciate your help, but I am fine.
5. I appreciate your help, but I can manage myself.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, *myself* means ***by*** myself (on my own, without assistance, etc.).

To *manage oneself* can mean *to personally handle **one's own particular circumstances and problems** (insofar as they need to be "managed")*. This emphasises the fact of the problems being "personal".

It's my opinion that adding ***by*** shifts the emphasis more to the fact of not needing assistance, but actually both forms are often used with this sense. It's also my opinion that both forms are *very* often spoken in a dismissive/hostile context - you actually *want* the other person to leave you alone to do whatever you need to on your own. Such a response is often followed by a sarcastic *"thank you!"* or *"thank you **very much**!"*

Leading on from that, I would be inclined to say that...

> "I can manage **on my own**, thank you"

...carries less risk of the hearer feeling that his offer of help has been somewhat rudely rejected.